# Can I prevent Chat/Hangouts window from loading in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When I'm on slow connection/slow browser, loading of Chat/Hangouts window in Gmail slows down opening of Gmail window a lot.

Is there a way to configure Gmail so that this window doesn't even start to load at all? (I don't use chat for this account so it is 100% useless to me.)

Just to be clear, I want to prevent the actual loading, NOT simply hide it but still load it in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Disable the chat in Gmail.

## Instructions

1. Go to gmail.com
2. Go to Settings > Chat
3. Click in the radio Chat off
4. Click the Save changes button